# android native webapplication , and html5 integration

Tags: html

I was about to start mobile web application development , I was looking a open source webapplication with which I can embedded to android web view. Native application developement + embedded web

Are there any webapplication with html5

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use cordova or phonegap(extends cordova) the use android web view and you can develop using html5

Refrences

[Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/)

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

You can use Angular.js or directly use ionic framework for building strong UI and front end logic for bussiness style apps. 
Further more you can integrate any javascript library or css UI like Bootstrap to Enhance the app.

Comment: Any thing more like liferay thng I can use??

Comment: You can build more things like it, its up to you. I have edited the answer